# What a4j eventsQueue should be replaced to?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm updating my RichFaces 3.3.3 to 4.5.2.Final and I need to replace

```
<a4j:support 
    event="change"
    eventsQueue="balbanceQueue"
    reRender=" dropCheck"/>
```

to the appropriate RichFaces 4.5.2.Final tag. As the migration guide stated, we should replace `a4j:support` with `a4j:ajax` and `reRender` with just `render`. But I couldn't find what `eventsQueue` attribute should be replaced with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. Use the `queueId` on the ajax tag:

   ```
   <a4j:ajax event="change" render="dropCheck" queueId="balbanceQueue"/>
   ```
2. Use the `a4j:attachQueue` component, nested within the component that'll trigger the ajax-request. This tag is used in combination with the `a4j:queue` component to provide [scoped ajax-queue definition](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Processing_management.html#sect-Component_Reference-queue-Queue_scopes). Using this, you should have something that looks like:

   ```
   <a4j:queue name="balbanceQueue"/>

   <h:inputText>
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="dropCheck"/>
        <a4j:attachQueue name="balbanceQueue"/>
   </h:inputText>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd like to clraify whether your 1st 2nd examples work the same? I mean I may use any of them.

Comment: You're welcome @user3663882. Yes, you can use either of them, #2 just gives a bit more control